# Linter not working for Java in Atom

Tags: java, javac, atom-editor, linter

I have the linter and linter-javac packages installed in Atom, however, none of my errors for .java files are ever linted. I have tested this by deliberately making mistakes like :

```
   int test = "test";
```

but the status on the bottom left corner still states: "No Errors".

Any idea on why this problem is being caused?

Answer (score 0):

try manually type "javac xxx.java"

if the error message is not english, linter-javac might miss the error message and shows "No Errors"

go to linter-javac settings, Additional Javac Options, add "-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

you might find this helpful, 
https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-javac/issues/36